# Design options for iPhone app with numerous (~50) screens, each with the same background

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm writing an iPhone app (which will be my first ios app) that has about 50 screens, each of which has the same background - where the background is an image covering the entire screen real estate and another image at the top as a banner.

Each screen will have some text along with 0, 1, 2 or 3 buttons appearing beneath the banner image.

What is the best design for putting this together?

The options I could think of were (in every each I was planning on having a root controller which is responsible for displaying each view as appropriate).
1) Have 50 separate screens as xibs (and associated view controllers), each of which contains the two background images plus however many buttons each particular screen needs.

2) Have 4 superclasses as xibs - (representing no buttons, 1 button, 2 button, 3 buttons) and have each of those contain the background images and as many buttons as appropriate. Then have 50 subclasses which simply just set the text and button content as appropriate using the superclasses instance variable outlets.

3) Have the root controller have a view which contains the two background images which is there permanently, and each of the 50 views displays its text and buttons on top of that.

4) (If this is possible, I need to check if a window can have images). Same as 3, except the root controller doesn't have a view, the main window displays the background images and each class displays its text and buttons on the top of this. So each view controller would have to load and display the text and button objects using code (in which case there's not much point to have xibs for them).

Is there another solution? Is one of these the "best" solution?

If I went with 3 would it not be possible to define the position text and buttons in a xib? (because in order to do so they would need a parent view in order to position them in interface builder, but if that were the case then when the view is drawn the background wouldn't be visible).

If 4 is possible, then the root controller has no view, therefore does it still need to be descended from UIViewController, or could it simply be descended from NSObject?

I think at the moment I am leaning towards option 2) as that way I can design all the views visually as xibs, but there are only 4 of them. Unless there is a better more elegant solution.

TIA

Comment: With 3, you can still use XIBs, because the parent view can be transparent.

Comment: Isn't transparency inherited by the children of that view so they buttons would be transparent also though>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is one XIB with all the buttons and then you would set then hidden accordingly. Although it would tie you up a bit. The 2) option is more flexible. The 3) is ok too. You could have one rootViewController, just to hold the images and then you could something like this:

```
[rootViewController.spaceForMyChildView addSubview: myNewViewController.view];
```

The "spaceForMyChildView" would be a view that would hold your child views.

I would do fusion between 2) and 3) probably.

Comment: Thank. I tried something as above as an experiment but nothing was displayed. [self.childView addSubview:childView.view] does do anything, ([self.view addSubview:childView.view] displays the child but the background goes away). I added childView as a UIView*. Have I missed something out or not set something up correctly?

Comment: You need to create "spaceForMyChildView" as an IBOulet... And connect it. Also, you need to set the backGround of your new ViewController as ClearColor, in order to see the your rootviewController's background.

Answer (score 0):

UIWindow inherits from UIView, so can have anything within it. So (4) is feasible, though you're starting to get into tricky water if you want to support any sort of view rotation.

I'd think an inverted (2) would be the easiest thing — have a single superclass that upon `viewDidLoad` adds the background and top banner programmatically. Have your specific controllers inherit from that and design them graphically to contain whatever you want, mindful that the image and banner will subsequently be added.

That said, if your views are really as simple as a single text area and up to three buttons, always with fixed positions, then it sounds like a single view that repopulates its fields from a data source, as Jacky Boy suggests, is probably the smartest thing.

Comment: Thanks. Is it important that the background/banner are loaded programatically? In other words, would it not work, and why, if there were in a xib? If the inheriting classes each has a view as a xib with child buttons etc., then when that view is displayed how do I make it not hide the background images?